# Audio files not deleting?

Tags: files, delete, motorola

Apologies if this has been answered, I attempted to search for answers and found nothing for my specific issue.

I've got several music files I'm trying to delete from my device (motorola e5 cruise, if this helps any) and while they stay deleted for around a day or so, they always come back fully. I can't get rid of them, and they take up a lot of space.

It's worth noting this device has given me grief as far as deletions before; it automatically deletes images after a day if I move them to a different folder, and I didn't notice until I would look for something important and find it gone. It's extremely frustrating, and I would appreciate any help I can get for these issues, but primarily the music files if you can. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are we talking about music you copied to the device or do they belong to an app? Are the music files saved in the "internal storage" section (`/sdcard`) or on an external sd-card? If it is the latter the app you use for deleting needs to request special permissions for deleting files on the external ad-card. If it just deletes them and does not check for errors the files are never deleted, just the central database entry is removed.

Comment: I'm a little ignorant of tech, so please excuse me if I answer poorly. It's music I've downloaded and doesn't belong to an app, and it's saved into my internal storage. So it doesn't need to ask for special permission in that case, right? Just in the case of it belonging to an app/it being saved to an external sd card?

Comment: I was asking because if it belongs to an app the might just restore the files. Hence it was the question to understand if the delete process just fails or is really done but later reverted. BTW: could you please edit your question and add the infor about your phone (manufacturer and model) + the user Android major version? Especially on Android 10+11 there were major changes that could be the reason for your problem if the used app for deleting is not yet Android 10/11 ready.

Comment: *"it automatically deletes images after a day if I move them to a different folder"* is there any app with cloud service used like google photos? *"they stay deleted for around a day or so, they always come back fully"* maybe the location is write protected? some devices run in emergency mode where the whole userdata partition is mounted read-only - that mean any changes will revert on reboot (even factory reset) i first heard about such thing 4 years ago https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3472891&page=2